# JAXB: How to bind element with namespace

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

He is my XML hosted on remote machine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<store xmlns="http://mydomain.com/store/schemas">
    <!-- My Book store-->
    <book location="vk 1">
        <title>Learning JAXB</title>
        <author>Joe Blogg</author>
    </book>
    <book location="vk 1">
        <title>Learning JAXB SE</title>
        <author>Joe Blogg</author>
    </book>
</store>
```

I have bind book as follows:

**Book Binding:**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "book")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "title", "author"})
public class Book
{
 private String title;
 private String author;
 private String location;

 @XmlElement(name = "title")
 public String getTitle()
 {
  return title;
 }

 public void setTitle(String title)
 {
  this.title=title;
 }

 @XmlAttribute(name = "location")
 public String getLocation()
 {
  return location;
 }

 public void setLocation(String location)
 {
  this.location = location;
 }

 @XmlElement(name = "author")
 public String getAuthor()
 {
  return author;
 }

 public void setAuthor(String author)
 {
  this.author = author;
 }
}
```

**Store Binding:**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "store", namespace = "http://mydomain.com/store/schemas")
public class Store
{
 private List<Book> books;

  @XmlElement(name="book")
  public List<Book> getBooks()
  {
    return books;
  }

  public void setBooks(List<Book> books)
  {
    this.books= books;
  }
}
```

I am unmarshalling the `XML` file as fAollows:

```
  JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Store.class);
  Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
  URL url = new URL("http://mydomain/files/store.xml");
  Store s= (Store) unmarshaller.unmarshal(url);
  System.out.println(s.getBooks());// Prints null
```

When I call `getBooks()` we get null value. Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong here?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [answer provided by skaffman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038821/jaxb-how-to-bind-element-with-namespace/8038850#8038850) is incorrect.  You can specify the namespace at the package level via `@XmlSchema` or at the class level using `@XmlType` and have it be used to qualify the fields/properties:

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: +1. XJC will use this mechanism when providing a package name for a schema in a bindings file. At least I've always seen it use `@XmlSchema` on `package-info.java` under those conditions from JAXB 2.1 RI onwards.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure but I think it might be possible to omit this duplication by using the @XmlSchema annotation on the package level (package-info.java).